# try to move a object in unity 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

The object is not moving down the slope i have also tried to reduce the friction to zero but not working and i am using a ball as my object

how to move an object in unity in 2d
Here is my code:

```
public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 3f;
    Rigidbody2D rig;
    float yat ;            
    void Start()
    {
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float xat = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        yat = rig.velocity.y;
        rig.velocity = new Vector2(xat*moveSpeed,yat);
    }
 }
```

Comment: You can use [AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) to move object.

Answer (score 0):

My apologize i don't get it exactly what you try to do? But if you simply moving the object you can try "Transfrom.Translate" method.

By the way, using velocity method try this code in your own version :

```
float speed = 0.5f;

...


void Update () {

      float inputHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
      player.velocity = Vector2.right * inputHorizontal * speed;
      
 }
```

Imo this should work, if you have any other query let me know.